# How to create a triggered update of cloud SQL instance export into SQL dump file in cloud storage?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I've got a cloud sql instance that uses a MySQL database. I have the database connexted to an external application which syncs with the databases and updates it whenever changes are made to the tables.

the end goal is to use this data with bigquery. Currently I;m manually exporting this to Cloud Storage Bucket but is there a way to schedule these exports to the same bucket because the data in BigQuery needs to be updated?

Comment: Thank you Graham, I will have a look at this

Comment: No problemo. I think it's what you need - or at least should be considering.